# Remove "default shipping address" from customers account

Tags: checkout, shipping, magento-1.9, customer, customer-account

So I have removed the "shipping address" from checkout page, and only using billing information. I also want to remove the option of "default shipping address" which is in customers account.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the template `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/customer/address/edit.phtml` you can see at the bottom there are two input items one for default shipping and one for default billing addresses.

```
<li<?php if($this->canSetAsDefaultShipping()) echo ' class="control"' ?>>
    <?php if($this->isDefaultShipping()): ?>
        <strong><?php echo $this->__('Default Shipping Address') ?></strong>
    <?php elseif($this->canSetAsDefaultShipping()): ?>
        <input type="checkbox" id="primary_shipping" name="default_shipping" value="1" title="<?php echo $this->__('Use as My Default Shipping Address') ?>" class="checkbox" /><label for="primary_shipping"><?php echo $this->__('Use as my default shipping address') ?></label>
    <?php else: ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="default_shipping" value="1" />
    <?php endif; ?>
</li>
```

What I would suggest is that you have two options.

1. Override the template used via layout xml and then simply remove this part from your new template.
2. Override the block so that the function `canSetAsDefaultShipping` always returns false.

Personally I would choose the template way at the moment as template changes feel easier to me.

If you have a sample layout xml the following snippet should work.

```
<customer_address_form>
    <reference name="customer_address_edit">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>your/path/to/template.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</customer_address_form>
```

Comment: I really don't know how to override the template.

Comment: @LuckyDhillon I have added the layout code that should do it for you. Does your theme have a local.xml layout file?

Comment: The one local.xml is in /public_html/app/design/frontend/ultimo/default/layout/local.xml and the other is in /public_html/app/etc/local.xml .. I am just working to get my checkout like this http://i1250.photobucket.com/albums/hh525/Dark934/checkout.jpg , http://i1250.photobucket.com/albums/hh525/Dark934/checkout2.jpg

Comment: @LuckyDhillon you could add this into there but it would break if you updated the ultimo design. If you are more comfotable you could rewrite the block instead.

Comment: i did some changes into styles.css and checkout page. 
check www.zumastic.com

Comment: it looks like you need to override something else too. If you edit and address that is default billing and shipping, and try to uncheck one of the checkboxes, it will still save for both address

Comment: @DavidManners a work-around for people who use themes they acquire, is to extend that theme. Under "Themes" in the system configuration area, Lucky could leave the "ultimo" theme as the "Default", then fill out his own theme name for translations, template, skin, and layout. This would result allowing him to use his own theme, which extends ultimo's, which extends Magento's default.